# Key Error when slicing in Pandas, but column exists?

Tags: python, pandas

My columns:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

print(df.columns)

Index(['ID', 'Start time', 'Completion time', 'Email', 'Name',
       'Last modified time', 'Report #1 Name', 'Type of Report',
       'Location of Report', 'Purpose of Report', 'Report Owner / Creator',
       'How often do you use this report?', 'Report #2 Name',
       'Type of Report2', 'Location of Report2', 'Purpose of Report2',
       'Report Owner / Creator2', 'How often do you use this report?2',
       'Report #3 Name', 'Type of Report3', 'Location of Report3',
       'Purpose of Report3', 'Report Owner / Creator3',
       'How often do you use this report?3'],
      dtype='object')
```

Let's check the data for column `Report #2 Name`

```
print(df['Report #2 Name'])


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Report #2 Name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14316\2316622378.py in <module>
----> 1 df['Report #2 Name']

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3456             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
...
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'Report #2 Name'
```

The same error occurs for `df['Report #3 Name']`

This works fine with no error:

```
df['Report #1 Name']

df['Purpose of Report2']

df['Type of Report3']
```

What's going on here? I thought the hash # symbol might be causing an error, but `df['Report #1 Name']` works fine.

edit: some more data for Panda Kim below in comments:

```
print('{}, {}'.format(df.columns, df.get('Report #2 Name', 'don exist')))


Index(['ID', 'Start time', 'Completion time', 'Email', 'Name',
       'Last modified time', 'Report #1 Name', 'Type of Report',
       'Location of Report', 'Purpose of Report', 'Report Owner / Creator',
       'How often do you use this report?', 'Report #2 Name',
       'Type of Report2', 'Location of Report2', 'Purpose of Report2',
       'Report Owner / Creator2', 'How often do you use this report?2',
       'Report #3 Name', 'Type of Report3', 'Location of Report3',
       'Purpose of Report3', 'Report Owner / Creator3',
       'How often do you use this report?3'],
      dtype='object'), don exist
```

Some more tests from comments below:

```
df.columns.union(['Report #2 Name'], sort=False)

Index(['ID', 'Start time', 'Completion time', 'Email', 'Name',
       'Last modified time', 'Report #1 Name', 'Type of Report',
       'Location of Report', 'Purpose of Report', 'Report Owner / Creator',
       'How often do you use this report?', 'Report #2 Name',
       'Type of Report2', 'Location of Report2', 'Purpose of Report2',
       'Report Owner / Creator2', 'How often do you use this report?2',
       'Report #3 Name', 'Type of Report3', 'Location of Report3',
       'Purpose of Report3', 'Report Owner / Creator3',
       'How often do you use this report?3', 'Report #2 Name'],
      dtype='object')
```

And

```
df.columns[12] == 'Report #2 Name'

False
```

And. This one seems to be the culprit.

```
df.columns[12].encode('utf-8')

b'Report #2\xc2\xa0Name'
```

Comment: 1- how did you build the DataFrame? 2- is this the full code? Are you sure you didn't modify `df`?

Comment: The only thing I did was `df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')`. It is data from Microsoft Forms. Nothing modified.

Comment: The error says that `print(df['Report #2 Name'])` is on line 1, which seems odd.  How can it be on line 1?  Surely there is other code before that?

Comment: @JohnGordon not in a notebook if this is the only line in a cell

Comment: It's in a notebook @JohnGordon

Comment: @SCool can you provide result of `print('{}, {}'.format(df.columns, df.get('Report #2 Name', 'don exist')))`

Comment: @PandaKim done. I added code to the main question.

Comment: If it's in a notebook, then my only explanation is that you have other code in a different cell that you didn't show, to remove that column.

Comment: And: `df.columns.union(['Report #2 Name'], sort=False)`?

Comment: Could you try `df.columns[12] == 'Report #2 Name'`, and see if that is True (I think I counted correctly, but please check).

Comment: It could be a different kind of space or a null spaced character, which we cannot see here

Comment: @mozway done  @ 9769953 done

Comment: @mozway so possibly microsoft forms inserted some weird space characters?

Comment: Try `df.columns[12].encode('utf-8')`, perhaps that shows an odd character.

Comment: @9769953  i got this: `b'Report #2\xc2\xa0Name'`

Comment: 'don exist' means that there is no 'Report #2 Name'. It seems that the actual text is different from other comment-like text. Check with `print(df.columns[12] == 'Report #2 Name')`.

Comment: There you go: \xc2\xa0 should be a simple space; that's the wrong character.

Comment: And `list(map(ascii, df))`?

Comment: There you are, it's a non-breaking space, not a normal space

Comment: Add the result with  `\xc2\xa0` to your question as well, since that's the really important part.

Comment: You can fix the names with `df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('\xc2\xa0', ' '))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-breaking space in your column name, as shown by `df.columns[12].encode('utf-8')`.

One solution, as suggested by mozway in the comments, is simply to rename the column(s) by replacing the non-breaking space by a normal space:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('\xc2\xa0', ' '))
```

This also takes care of any erroneous spaces in other column names. (But it won't handle other infamous odd characters, such as “smart” quotes.)

Comment: I've added an answer, as there was a solution given in the comments, but comments may not be read that easily (it's rather a lenghty set of debugging comments), and they can (easier) be deleted altogether without a trace.

Comment: The comment exchange solves OP's problem, but it doesn't lead to an answer suitable for Stack Overflow, because the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Issues like this are considered to be "not reproducible or caused by a typo", because the data was simply not what OP believed it to be. Alternately, it could be closed as a duplicate of a question about how to verify the contents of a string more precisely - I'm sure there are plenty of those available.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Go ahead close it as a duplicate or not suitable. After all, the next person who searches for "KeyError in Pandas but column exists" won't be helped by this Q&A. /s

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to "/s" that. Unironically, the next person who searches that **is very likely not** to be helped by this, because there are **any number of other reasons** why someone could mistakenly believe the "column exists".

Comment: Because this question and its resolution is certainly one option to explore if you have this error. I don't see how that is not helpful.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution on stack overflow. There are questions with similar titles but none had the same issue as me.